# Partial View in jQuery Dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Here is my controller and I am using primary key as string.

When I click on detail link the employee send to controller and controller search get by id employee and return partial view with employee detail

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
    var data = oj.GetById(id);
    return PartialView("~/Views/Partial/Details.cshtml", data);
}
```

Here is my view

```
@model HIRS_System.Models.Details
<fieldset>
    <legend>Details</legend>
    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dept_id)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.emp_id)
    </div>
    <div class="display-label">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.emp_fname)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.emp_fname)
    </div>

    .... // other properties

    <div class="display-label">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dept_id)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.dept_id)
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Database `GetById` code

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetById(string id)
{
    return obj.Employees.Where(x => x.emp_id == id);
}
```

My problem is when is click the detail button partial view shows this error

[image]

If I use `@model IEnumerable<HIRS_System.Models.Details>`

then it shows this error

[image]

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Your view is declared with `@model HIRS_System.Models.Details` but you pass it `IEnumerable<Employee>`

Comment: what is `HIRS_System.Models.Details` class supposed to be and why are you trying to pass a `IEnumerable<Employee>` to the view instead?

Comment: Employee is Data Layer

Comment: Please edit your question to use proper capitalization and interpunction.

Comment: and  Hirs_System.Modes.Details    is Presentation Layer

Comment: So how do you expect `IEnumerable<Employee>` to magically map itself to an instance of `Hirs_System.Modes.Details`?

Comment: I am using  @model IEnumerable< DataLayer.Employee>   or DataLayer.Employee    but same above

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want `GetById()` to return zero or one employees, so change the method to return `Employee` instead:

```
public Employee GetById(string id)
{
    return obj.Employees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.emp_id == id);
}
```

Then change your view to actually use that type:

```
@model DataLayer.Employee
```

Comment: @model IEnumerable< DataLayer.Employee>          i ma using this or  DataLayer.Employee  but error same above

Comment: Yeah because you don't need IEnumerable to display one.